# Style `wp list` categories with bootstrap

Tags: php, css, wordpress, styles, wp-list-categories

Regards , 
I am trying to style the list of categories put i dont know what i must search for & in so i have this html code styled with bootstrap 
`wp_list_categories();`

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark our-color fixed-top">
    <div class="container"> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/logo-woocommerce-white.png" width="150" height="30" alt=""> </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto s">
                <li class="nav-item active bold"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">الرئيسية<span class="sr-only">(current)</span> </a> </li>
  <?php wp_list_categories(); ?>
                <li class="nav-item bold"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">خدمات</a> </li>
                <li class="nav-item bold"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">اتصل بنا</a></li>
            </ul>
 </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I want to import the categories of `Wordpress` in this classes > the if I put it in a `div` it's not affecting the list, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

**You can style it as follows**

```css
li{
list-style-type:none;
padding:10px;
border-radius:4px;
background:black;
margin-bottom:2px;

}

li a{
color:#fff;
text-decoration:none;
}

li:hover{
background:red;
transition:all 0.3s;
color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark our-color fixed-top">
  <div class="container"> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/logo-woocommerce-white.png" width="150" height="30" alt=""> </a>
   <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"> <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> </button>
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto s">
     <li class="nav-item active bold"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">الرئيسية<span class="sr-only">(current)</span> </a> </li>
     <?php wp_list_categories(); ?>
     <li class="nav-item bold"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">خدمات</a> </li>
     <li class="nav-item bold"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">اتصل بنا</a> </li>
     
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
 </nav>
```

> Hope this will work. All the best. for any query please comment

Comment: thanks put incorrect answer , i wanna style the list generated by wp_list_categories in wordpress